# jQuery: Add Class Active to <a> with current page href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, class, tabs

I am looking for a way to add an active class to the  tag that has an href of the current page.

Say I am on the page localhost:3000/inbox, I need my html to change add the correct class to the correct  which are all located in the div with the class sidebar.

So when at "/inbox" jQuery should make my html look like this:

```
<div class="sidebar">
<a href="/link">
  <i class="fa fa-inbox"></i>
  <span>A Link</span>
</a>
<a class="active" href="/inbox">
  <i class="fa fa-inbox"></i>
  <span>Inbox</span>
</a>
</div>
```

This is what I tried, but it doesn't work, it breaks the code:

```
var href = $(location).attr('href');
  ('.sidebar').find('a[href*=href]').addClass("active");
```

Thank you. Please let me know if I wasn't clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
var path = window.location.pathname;
$(".sidebar a[href*='"+path+"']").addClass("active");
```

Please note the `'` around the path. They are there because jQuery cause syntax error if there are unquoted `/` in the selector.

When I try it on JSFiddle, I get a `/` at the end of the path. You might want to add that to your links, or you can remove it from the `path` variable like this:

```
if(path.charAt(path.length-1) == "/")
    path = path.substring(0, path.length - 1);
```

Then some browsers might not include the leading `/` (or at least I think so), so you might want to add it in case it isn't already there:

```
if(path.charAt(0) != "/")
    path = "/" + path;
```

Since you use `*=` you might match more than the current page. For instance, if you are on `/inbox/` you will also add the class to links to `/inbox/sub/folder`. To avoid this, use `=` instead.

Taken together, you would get this:

```
var path = window.location.pathname;
if(path.charAt(path.length-1) == "/")
    path = path.substring(0, path.length - 1);
if(path.charAt(0) != "/")
    path = "/" + path;
$(".sidebar a[href='"+path+"']").addClass("active");
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/1nyz5f9t/3/) is a working JSFiddle. (You might need to press run to make it work, as the URL is different the first time the page load.)

Comment: Something in this line is breaking my code: $('.sidebar a[href*='+path+']').addClass("active");

Comment: Fixed by changing single quotes to double quotes.

Comment: Checked /companies is in fact what I get after the if but for some reason it does not set the active class...

Comment: You did not copy my code correctly. I fixed it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/1nyz5f9t/2/), but it still does not work jQuery seems to have a problem with `/` in selectors. I will look into it.

Comment: Ok, needed to add `'` around the URL. [This](http://jsfiddle.net/1nyz5f9t/3/) one is working (you might need to press run, though).

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're almost doing it right, with the minor mistake of forgetting to call `jQuery` or `$`. You also need to concatenate your selector, so that the *value* of href is searched for.

```
$('.sidebar').find('a[href*="' + href + '"]').addClass('active');
```

You probably also need to find just the path name to match your `href` values, like so:

```
var href = window.location.pathname;
```

Comment: Do you need the match the whole url when you're already searching for the containing value using *= ?  Wouldn't the first line be enough on its own?

Comment: Doesn't quiet work for me... Why could that be? What does '/' + window.location.pathname return? When I inscpect element the class is not there.

Comment: [This](http://jsfiddle.net/sLL9qL8p/1/) fiddle shows me the pathname with the leading `/` already included. Adding it again would cause the code not to work. Might this be browser dependent?

Comment: Updated; removed the leading slash. My mistake on that one. Also, as per @Anders's solution, added the interior quotes around the href value in the jQuery selector.

Comment: You need to use var href = window.location.pathname+window.location.search; to include the query path ?q=...

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your question you want to change all divs that have a href of '/inbox' to have the class "active"

Your code should therefore look like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

     $(.sidebar a[href=='/inbox']){

         $(a[href=='/inbox').addClass('active');

     }

}
```

Comment: Well I more specifically need it to add the class active if the href match the current page href.